# Copying addresses of objects containing an atomic member?

Tags: c++, c++11, atomic

Lets say I have a struct `AtomicElement`:

```
struct AtomicElement{
    std::atomic<int32_t> a;
};
```

and I have another class, `Object`, which contains a reference to one of the above `AtomicElement` objects:

```
struct Object{
    AtomicElement& ae;
};
```

Now elsewhere I have a vector of these `AtomicElement` objects and I would like to update `Object::ae` to point to different vector elements:

```
std::vector<AtomicElement> aeVector(AtomicElement());
Object obj;
.
.
//Obtain the address to the new element
AtomicElement& raw_ae = aeVector[i];
.
.
//Change to point to the new element
obj.ae = raw_ae;  //Cannot get this part to compile.
```

What am I doing wrong?

My `AtomicElement` is only 32 bits, should I just be using by value?

I want to do this in the most efficient way possible, with as little copying as possible.

EDIT:

The 32-bit int is actually representing two 16-bit numbers and the atomicity is so the value is updated.... atomically. **I'm wondering if I'd be better off defining a copy constructor as copying 32-bit int would be quicker than pointer dereferencing?**

Comment: It looks like you're using references where you want to use pointers. The `obj.ae = raw_ae` line does not change the `obj.ae` reference, but rather attempts to copy the object referenced by `raw_ae` into the object referenced by `obj.ae`. Since `AtomicElement` is non-copyable (because of its `std::atomic` member which is non-copyable), this doesn't work.

Comment: Can you expand upon what you're trying to accomplish? Why do you need an atomic member? Why all the indirection? Perhaps there's a more direct way to achieve the efficiency you desire.

Comment: @Cameron the 32bits actually represents two 16-bit numbers, which much be in synch with each other all the time. Would it be more efficient for me to define a copy constructor and therefore writing a 32-bit int is more efficient than dereferencing/pointers etc?

Comment: It really depends on what you're doing with these structs. It may not even be possible to define a meaningful copy constructor if you want to copy the AtomicElement around while other threads are using it. In general, though, the less indirection the better.

Comment: @Cameron all I am doing is setting the two 16-bit values together at the same time and then occasionally reading one or the other. I currently use a union consisting of two 16-bit ints, with a 32-bit int. Then, this class is data member of a class with a single 32-bit atomic uint32_t. The atomic class has wrapper functions doing exchange/compare_exchange on the data member.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't reassign references, but you can use pointers. (Would have commented but don't have the rep.)

However, since an std::atomic is (most likely, but depends on your architecture) useful because of *the way it funnels all access through atomic member functions*, not because of any *extra member data* that makes it atomic, copying it around is probably equivalent to copying an int, and it may indeed be faster if you don't need reference semantics, because dereferencing memory is relatively slow. As mentioned in the comments, you'll have to define what it means to copy it to satisfy your needs.

Comment: Note that a `std::atomic<int>` is not intrinsically copyable, though -- you have to define your own semantics of what it means to copy it.

Comment: @Cameron definitely, I have added a note to reflect your comment.

Answer (score 0):

`Type & value = reference;`is more and less similar to `Type * const value = &reference` while to set a value you need to do so respectively through `value = Type()` and `*value = Type()`. As a fact, you **CANNOT** change the address of a reference in both ways once defined and it is mandatory to define them at their declaration.

In your case, the issue is that by doing `obj.ae = raw_ae;` you are not attempting to change the reference but to assign a new value to the current referencee of *obj.ae*. As `std::atomic` is declared as a non-copyable class, you got an appropriate compiler error.

If you need to be able to switch to another referencee, you must use a pointer instead.